# How do I delete or close a graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I delete or close a graph?

I had defined a function to plot a graph. However, whenever I change the variable and close the matplotlib window and draw a new graph, the previous graph is not deleted. Below is my program:

```
def graphforcevsmass():

 global velocityvalue
 global radiusvalue 

 for i in range(101):
    j = i * float(int(velocityvalue) ** 2 / int(radiusvalue))

    x.append(i)
    y.append(j)

 plt.plot(x, y)
 plt.draw()
```

In my program, I used a button to activate the function above and the variable will change depending on the scale in the tkinter window.
(I am coding python in enthought canopy using tkinter and matplotlib module)

Comment: Do you mean closing a tkinter window that has a matplotlib graph embedded?

Comment: yes i mean closing a tkinter window that has a matplotlib graph embedded.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it would be to use

```
plt.clf() # Clear figure
```

before plotting the new variables.